# How can I filter based on Just One Record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, where-clause

I am trying to write a query based on 2 components. I have two fields called 'Plan_code' and another field called 'PolicyNum'. I have multiple records of 'PolicyNum', but they will have unique 'Plan_code' associated to them. What I want to find is if one of the 'PolicyNum' duplicates have 'Plan_Code' of 1, to pull all the PolicyNum duplicates. When I write the below query

```
SELECT PolicyNum
,Plan_Code

FROM [dbo].[IMS_IFCRP01_AA]

WHERE Plan_Code = '1'
```

I will only get that one record where a PolicyNum will have Plan_Code = 1. I need all the duplicates of the PolicyNum's for this analysis. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is Gordon Linoffs answer not what you need? Then please specify what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `exists` or `in`:

```
SELECT ia.*
FROM [dbo].[IMS_IFCRP01_AA] ia
WHERE ia.PolicyNum IN (SELECT ia2.PolicyNum 
                       FROM [dbo].[IMS_IFCRP01_AA] ia2
                       WHERE ia2.Plan_Code = '1'
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need dublicate PolicyNum.

```
SELECT 
    PolicyNum
FROM [dbo].[IMS_IFCRP01_AA]
WHERE
   Plan_Code = '1' 
GROUP BY 
    PolicyNum
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: but he wants to see duplicate PolicyNums for Plan_Code = 1, not the all records.

Comment: Thank you! that is close, but I'll need the dupes only for the plan_code's that I am filtering on. Those plan codes are unique for each PolicyNum duplicate

Comment: Ok, he forgot the where clause, but that does't mean you can't use your imagination a bit. He provided you the key answer to the problem in my opinion.

Comment: But that wont get me what I need. I understand what he's trying to do, but not all the records are duplicated, only the PolicyNum's. Can't do a COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: Could you give some sample data and expected result?